# What are map files and how to use them to debug a program?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, gdb

I am trying to learn **map** files to debug a crash in a stripped executable.
Can anyone please provide pointers to

1. How to debug a stripped executable using map files?

Thanks,
Sheeri

Comment: Please give some reference for your *map files* (for me, there are a linker thing).

Comment: yes, I am referring to the same 'map' files of linker.